# QuickTime Player: How to Reduce Playback Speed?

Tags: video, quicktime

In QuickTime Player, I'd like to play the video back at slower than real-time speeds. I see that it's possible to play back at *faster* than real time speeds -- by pressing the option key and clicking the Fast Forward and Rewind buttons. How can I play video at slower speeds?

I'm running QuickTime player 10.4 on OSX 10.11.x

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Slow Motion Forward: Hold K+L together (this gives you audio) or hold right-arrow. 
Slow Motion Reverse: Hold J+K together (this gives you audio) or hold left-arrow.

Comment: Is there some guide somewhere that documents these commands for QuickTime? I have not been able to find a comprehensive one.